# how to handle>>{object promise} error while am trying to create slc loopback:relation

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback, loopback-address

[image]Am new bee to loopback. i have generated loopback API model using loopback arc generator. But it generated models and API's without table relationship(such as key constraints). Is there any other method to generator for generating API model with table relation. I have tryed (slc loopback:relation) am getting the below mentioned error. Am using latest node version (6.2.0). How can i handle this error kindly help me out of it. Thanks in advance

> (node:6516) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported.
>   If you are  using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more
>   recent version. ? Select the model to create the relationship from:
>   Vendor ? Relation type: has many ? Choose a model to create a
>   relationship with: VendorProfile ? Enter the property name for the
>   relation: (vendorProfiles)
>
> > > [object Promise]